# C: Ask for inputs as an array

Tags: c

I would like to ask user's input to form an integer array. And if one input gets invalid, which is not integer, the current array will be printed and ask the user to continue entering numbers from the last position. This is my code, but it is not working. What should I do?

```
int A[SIZE], i;

    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        A[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("Enter %d numbers as an array: ", SIZE);
    i = 0; // Initialize i
    while (i<SIZE) {
        for (i=i; i<SIZE; i++) {
            if (!scanf("%d", &A[i])) {
                printf("Invalid input!\n");
                printarray(A, SIZE);
                printf("i = %d", i);
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: "it is not working" <- please be explicit. What do you expect and what is happening now. Give a [mcve]. Try and learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Either `while (i<SIZE)` or `for(i...` but not both

Comment: `printarray(A, i);` because the array is not yet full.

Comment: Use `while(scanf(...)!=1) {` to loop until correct input has been received from the user.

Comment: Once `scanf` fails, it's going to continue to fail until you clear the input buffer. Also note that your `if` statement doesn't handle EOF, which is a non-zero value.

Comment: @user3386109, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user enters something other than an integer, `scanf` will continue failing because the input is still there. One way to solve this is reading line by line using `fgets` and then using `sscanf` to scan the line for a number. You also should only increase `i` if the input is valid.

Combined with the other comments, you can get something like this:

```
int i=0;
while(i<SIZE)
{
    char line[100];
    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
    if(sscanf(line, "%d", &A[i]) == 1)
        ++i;
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid input!\n");
        printArray(A, i);
        printf("i = %d", i);
    }
}
```

You should add error handling for `fgets` and `sscanf`. `fgets` returns `NULL` on error and `sscanf` returns `EOF` on an error.